# How do I write a bash script that deletes my system log files after asking for permission at a certain time everyday?

Tags: bash, macos, scripting, hardware

I want to write a bash script that deletes my system logs once a day at, say, 9PM Eastern Standard Time.

I'm relatively inexperienced.

```
#!/bin/sh
# I would want it to self-execute at some time every day.
# Would that mean that the shell needs to always run in the background?
# Is there a method by which I can add this execution to a daemon or other 
# background-process's code-content? (If so please give me details)

touch /Permission.txt            

#^^Process creates a file in root directory

chflags nouchg /Permission.txt

#^^Just in case the "no changes" flag is on, preventing me from changing 
#  permissions

chmod 0747 /Permission.txt 

#^^Sets permissions so that I can write to the file without being root.
#  I also set group permissions to read-only, my logic being that I want
#  raw data to go into this file without it being modified by shared  
#  Ownership processes..? 

echo "Delete System Logs for: "%d"/"%m"/"%y" ?">/Permission.txt
open /Permission.txt
Input=/Permission.txt</dev/f0

#^^Not just for the purposes of this script but for future scripts-I want
#  to capture raw binary data from peripheral devices. Is the output
#  of the keyboard interpreted by the OS or any other process before saving
#  to the text file?
#  How do I get raw binary-output to a file from hardware devices? How can
#  I go about understanding the opcode syntax-whether it uses even or odd
#  parity; whether it is big or small endian; and other binary nuances. 

while [ $Input != "Exit" ]
 do
  read /Permission.txt
   if [ $Input == "Yes"|"yes" ]; then
    echo "Exit">/Permission.txt
     echo "sudo rm -rf /private/var/log/* ;">ttys000     #See 1 below
      echo "********"                                  #The Password
       fi
   if [ $Input == "No"|"no" ]; then
    echo "Exit">/Permission.txt
     fi
end
#  1 not sure where the process is in the system and whether or not sending 
#  that string to tty will result in the command being executed as if terminal
#  were running, will the ";" be seen as the return button being pressed?
```

I want this to listen for the pattern "Yes" or "No" or its binary equivalent. How will the "read" command work in the while loop? How do I ensure that it reads for a certain pattern? Will the for loop function properly even after it enters "Exit" thereby closing the while loop, IE, will closing the parent process within the child process immediately interrupt the child process?

Comment: On unix-style systems, periodic jobs are normally performed by cronjobs. Especially for logfiles, there is logrotate. But these programs normally work without interaction, especially not GUI-interaction and it is a bit complicated, to make them start GUI programs. But I'm in the Linux world, not MacOS. However, these solutions are very old, so they have gone through a long path of collecting experience. IE what to do, if the machine isn't running at the specific time. On Xubuntu, however, I would try to look, whether the calendar app, Orage, can handle this.

Comment: It can't be complicated. Something like "If [ %h = 18 ]; then; run process; fi"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
# I would want it to self-execute at some time every day.
# Would that mean that the shell needs to always run in the background?
```

If you think of the implications of running in the foreground, you will understand why it needs to run in the background. What if you're not logged-in at that exact time? What if you're typing a document? You might consider creating a pop-up window (Windows-style), but where? Which console?

```
# Is there a method by which I can add this execution to a daemon or other 
# background-process's code-content? (If so please give me details)
```

Try `man crontab`. In the crontab, you can specify how often jobs must run (for example:

```
#  m    h  D   M  dow  cmd
   0    3  *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/backup.diaadm
```

runs, on my system, a backup of my diapositives-administration every night at 3:00.

```
touch /Permission.txt
```

It is a bad idea to create files like this in the root-directory. It should probably be in a directory under `/var/local` somewhere.

```
# Process creates a file in root directory
chmod 0747 /Permission.txt 
# Sets permissions so that I can write to the file without being root.
# I also set group permissions to read-only, my logic being that I want direct
# and raw data to go into this file without it being modified by shared  
# Ownership processes..?
```

747 is a bizarre permission. If you're on a multi-user system, it should (probably) be 0774 and you put the administrators in the correct group.

I do not understand your flawed logic. You do not want the data to be modified by shared access, but you give write permissions to the world (=everyone on the system)?

```
echo "Delete System Logs for: "%d"/"%m"/"%y" ?">/Permission.txt
open /Permission.txt
Input=/Permission.txt</dev/f0
```

I am not sure what you are trying to establish here. It is not valid bash-scripting.

```
# Not just for the purposes of this script but for future scripts-I want to be
# able to capture raw binary data from peripheral devices. Is the output
# of the keyboard interpreted by the OS or any other process before saving
# to the text file?
# How do I get raw binary-output to a file from hardware devices? How can
# I go about understanding the opcode syntax-whether it uses even or odd
# parity; whether it is big or small endian; and other binary nuances.
```

In general, peripheral devices  under Unix are represented by a device-file under `/dev`. You should be able to do a `cat /dev/devicename` to read the input from a device. However, if you want to use raw input from a device, `bash` might not be the right tool. Perl and Python have better support for these kind of things, and C or C++ is best suited for these kind of jobs.

```
while read Input ; do

   if [ $Input == "Yes"|"yes" ]; then
      echo "Exit">/Permission.txt
```

Here, you overwrite the file that you are reading. I do not understand why and it seems so illogical that I doubt that you want that.

```
     echo "sudo rm -rf /private/var/log/*"
     echo "********"                                  #The Password
```

Using sudo in a script is not a great idea. You should make sure that a script runs under the right permissions. Echoing the password is a bad idea. If you must, you can set-up passwordless sudo vis `visudo`.

```
   fi
```

if [ $Input == "No"|"no" ]; then
    echo "Exit">/Permission.txt

see my previous comment on this.

```
 fi
```

end

end?

```
#  1 not sure where the process is in the system and whether or not sending 
#  that string to tty will result in the command being executed as if terminal
#  were running, will the ";" be seen as the return button being pressed?
```

No. Why would it? Echoing to the tty echoes to the tty.

You were probably trying something like this:

```
while read Input ; do
 if [ $Input = "Yes" ]; then
    sudo rm -rf /private/var/log/* ;
 elif [ $Input = "No" ]; then
    exit
 fi
done < /Permission.txt
```

You should also, at least put your code through shellcheck.

Comment: This is being applied to my personal computer.

When I set the permissions to 0747, the only groups in the "everyone" category is whatever user I am, I don't always know what user I am, I don't understand what defines a "user". I set the shared access to read only in hopes that some background agent with shared permissions doesn't effect the output, for future instances when I read from devices for raw unaltered data.

I open the text file so that it appears on the screen, so that I don't have to remember. It doesn't have to be in the background for it to work. The file will remain open.

Comment: I overwrite the file because I don't want to work in that file at all. In fact I want to remove the file just after completing the process.

The file is a sort of communication channel between the process and myself. It is merely used as a way to A) remind me to delete system logs and B) ask me just in case I want to save those logs.

I don't see why I can't just have the output of the keyboard held in /dev/f0 output to the txt file? Why do I "need" a different language?

Comment: I've never heard a good argument for why I shouldn't let the process run with root privileges. It's the exact same thing as me running with root privileges, in the sense that this process is doing exactly as I tell it. I'm open to an explanation

Comment: There are a lot of misunderstandings here. First the permisions and the user. What you effectively do with 747 is create a blacklist-group. Anyone not in the blacklist-group is allowed write-access to the file. I have in real life never seen an application for this. In general, there are but a few world writable's in your filesystem (use `find / -perm -o+w ` to find them).  In Unices, world writable's are seen as security issues (with the stickybit as mitigating measure).

Comment: The second is which user you are. You are the user on the system that you have logged into, unless you su-ed to another user. That can be via `su`, `sudo`, a set-uid program or other means. That is how most Unix users look at it. If you want to go deeper than that, google for "real uid effective uid, saved uid". If you are in doubt, `id` will show you which user you are.

Comment: "I overwrite the file because I don't want to work in that file at all". Now I'm lost. The rest of your comment suggests that you might want a FIFO (`man mkfifo`), but then you seriously need to rethink your workflow.   As I stated in the answer: yes you can have the input from a device file using bash. Note that there are probably other processes as well that read that stream, so you might get just a few characters.  And your other programs will probably also miss a few characters, but if that's what you want.

Comment: The problem with bash is that it has a limited number of ways to interact with the device files. Perl and Python are more flexible, and C gives you low-level control; you might even write your own device driver.

Comment: You may also want to do a bit of reading on Unix security if you've never heard an argument for not running as root. Anyway, I did not suggest that you should not run as root. You might want to re-read my answer at that point.

Comment: Does running as root affect the status of my firewalls? If not then external programs are in no better position to exploit me. Does running as root, in any way, affect where data is stored? If not then the only issue I’ll have is extra effort changing permissions of files created by the program. Of course, using anything that involves communication with the internet as a root user might not be a good idea. I’m trying to figure how, I just get the feeling that it increases my systems vulnerability. Does accessing the internet as root user give network servers more power over my system?

Comment: I don’t understand what a FIFO file is, I saw it stands for first in first out, isn’t that just the orientation? I assume a FIFO file has the alternative “LIFO” file, and I assume that it is used to simply take output “as is” from a device and store it unchanged unlike, I assume, a text file does. I don’t understand the notion that I should change my workflow. I don’t develop for any company, I just learn and write something here and there—something that usually doesn’t work. I’ve been programming for roughly three weeks seriously, I’ve played around a bit before—I’m just getting serious now

Comment: Please read https://www.howtogeek.com/124950/htg-explains-why-you-shouldnt-log-into-your-linux-system-as-root/ ; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52268/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-run-as-root; http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash